# Attempting to install overgrive but getting dpkg/python error

Tags: software-installation, google-drive

I am attempting to install [overgrive](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/overgrive) on a ubuntu 15.04 machine but consistently get the error below. Does anyone know the issue that is occurring?

I have tried to contact the team, but I can't find a direct email address, and their contact page is broken.

---

```
$ sudo dpkg -i overgrive_3.1.2_all.deb
Selecting previously unselected package overgrive.
(Reading database ... 407549 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack overgrive_3.1.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking overgrive (3.1.2) ...
Setting up overgrive (3.1.2) ...
Downloading/unpacking google-api-python-client
  Downloading google_api_python_client-1.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (48kB): 48kB downloaded
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 304, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1260, in prepare_files
    )[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Storing debug log for failure in /home/sbi6dap/.pip/pip.log
dpkg: error processing package overgrive (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.44.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.44.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+15.04.20150202-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 overgrive
```

---

I have also pasted my pip.log at http://pastebin.com/qeu7gF9X

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `pip --version`. If the outputted version is lower than **7.1.2** (latest available version on 2015/10/12), you might want to upgrade it (`sudo -H pip install --upgrade pip`) and try again.

Comment: How the hell was I running pip version 1.5?? I have no idea how I was so outdated! Thank you, this has fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the standard Ubuntu repositories, `pip` is only available in the pretty outdated version **1.5.6**, as can be seen in the example output below of my 15.04 installation:

```
$ apt-cache policy python-pip
python-pip:
  Installed: 1.5.6-5ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1.5.6-5ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 1.5.6-5ubuntu2 0
        500 http://[...]/ubuntu/ vivid/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

However, on **PyPI** (**Py**thon **P**ackage **I**ndex), the place where `pip` gets its packages from and which can always be considered up to date, the latest available version is currently (Oct 12, 2015) version **7.1.2**.

It is known that the old `pip` **1.5.6** often causes problems when other, newer Python packages get installed. It either breaks entirely after having installed e.g. the Python package `requests`, or as in your case, fails to install a specific Python package.

To fix this problem and be able to install `overgrive`, you just have to upgrade your currently installed `pip` with the **PyPI** version, not through `apt-get` from the repositories. To do so, just perform the following command:

```
sudo -H pip install --upgrade pip
```

The command above installs `pip` **7.1.2** (or newer) from **PyPI** to your system. The old **1.5.6** version of `pip` from the repository will still be available, but when you just type `pip` into the terminal without an absolute path, the version installed through `pip` itself will always be preferred. You should not uninstall the repository version of `pip` using `apt-get` though, because that might lead to dependency problems. Just leave and ignore it.

To update `pip3`, which is `pip` for Python 3, you would use the following command instead:

```
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

If `pip` is broken and fails to install anything, you may temporarily use `easy_install` instead to get the latest version which usually fixes the problem. The commands for Python 2 and 3 respectively would be:

```
sudo -H easy_install --upgrade pip
sudo -H easy_install3 --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise you forget overGrive. I've had my own problems, not only with the program itself, but with the programmer/company owner. He cursed me out for a simple inquiry about registration and has remained unresponsive. At this point, I'd suggest just using the Google Drive web site until/unless Google starts supporting Linux. Every other program to support Linux is overpriced or (in the case of overGrive) doesn't work.